# Extract a previous version of file that is stored within a tar archive

Tags: backup, archive, tar, archive-tar

I have a tar file which contain different versions of the same file, how can I extract one of the previous version of the file (not the last version) ?

**here is how to create a test tar file:**

*create a test directory*

```
tal@backup:~/tmp$ mkdir test
```

*create a test file*

```
tal@backup:~/tmp$ echo line 1 > test/test.txt
```

*create the tar file which contains the test file*

```
tal@backup:~/tmp$ tar -cvf test.tar test/*
```

*returns*

```
test/test.txt
```

*check for changes*

```
tal@backup:~/tmp$ tar -dvf test.tar test/*
```

*returns (nothing yet)*

```
test/test.txt
```

*change the test file*

```
tal@backup:~/tmp$ echo line 2 >> test/test.txt
```

*check for changes*

```
tal@backup:~/tmp$ tar -dvf test.tar test/*
```

*returns (magic: the file has changed)*

```
test/test.txt
test/test.txt: Mod time differs
test/test.txt: Size differs
```

*update the tar file*

```
tal@backup:~/tmp$ tar -uvf test.tar test/*
```

*returns*

```
test/test.txt
```

*check for changes*

```
tal@backup:~/tmp$ tar -dvf test.tar test/*
```

*returns (both versions exist)*

```
test/test.txt
test/test.txt: Mod time differs
test/test.txt: Size differs
test/test.txt
```

Thanks,
Tal

Answer (score 3):

Solved:

**--occurrence=n**

*n - [0 .. number of versions]*

- 0 - last one (default)
- 1 .. number of version - is the actual number of version
- error occur if n is larger then number of versions

**example**

```
tar -xvf test.tar --occurrence=1 test/test.txt
```

Thanks,
Tal